# OpenFlow bug details

Tags: specifications, openflow

I'm reading changelists of OpenFlow specifications and see that each change has bug tracking ID. For example "Clarify the mapping of encapsulation data in OXM_OF_TUNNEL_ID **(EXT-161)**".

I cannot find any OpenFlow bug trackers or anything else that will provide detailed bug information. Can anyone help me to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the bugtracker is that it's referring to, but the EXT-* numbers are extensions. There is documentation on the extensions [here](https://www.opennetworking.org/sdn-resources/technical-library), in the "OpenFlow Extensions" packages. They each have a bunch of documents about the extensions bundled together.

However, EXT-161 does not appear to be documented in these packs.